# How can I create a Django form out of a Model with 3 fields using the first field as the label, the rest as radio checks?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django model that has 3 fields:

The name of the item

The price of the small size

The price of the large size

Id like to create a form that looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9spSK.png)

The name of the item is essentially the label for the 2 succeeding radio checks.

I'm not sure how to go about creating this type of form. I'd only like for one of the radio checks to be selected at a time. Do I have to iterate over every object in the database?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to write the form in HTML. Just create a table with 3 columns, one being the Label, the other ones being the two prices. Put radio buttons into the second and third column, give them the same "name"-attribute (e.g. radio_{{ label }} ) and voilá.

You can then later get the selected values in your django POST view.

EDIT: oh and yeah, write the above as a template and apply it to all of your items.